# TFS 2015 - Track "Doing and Done" subcolumns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, tfs-2015, kanban

I'm using TFS 2015 and I'm trying to write a SQL Query to track the Cycle Times within a sprint.

My "Development" column on the Kanban board is using the option for "Doing and Done" subcolumns:

[image]

My goal is to write a SQL Query that tracks the time between a work item being moved to the "Doing" subcolumn until it reaches "Verified" status.

I can't find anywhere in the database where we'd be tracking whether a work item is in either of those subcolumns.  There is a **System_BoardColumn** field in the **WORKITEMHISTORYVIEW** view in **TFS_M3WAREHOUSE**, but this appears to be skipping the Development step completely.

Does anyone know how I can track that info in SQL Server?

Comment: It's not suggest to make your hands dirty in TFS database, which may not get  official support from Microsoft. Instead of using SQL query to track the Cycle Times. You could also consider to use some 3rd-party such as [Timetracker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Berichthaus.TfsTimetracker),  that could  tracks the time between a work item being moved to the "xxx" subcolumn until it reaches "xxx" status. and even remembers which work items were in progress on which days--without you having to rack your brain.